# How to get list<string> value using foreach in another form in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, list, collections

I wants to get the `List<string>` values in another form using `foreach` loop

**ReportTestForm.cs**

```
private void ReportTestForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> fieldList = new List<string>();

    fieldList.Add("Name");
    fieldList.Add("Class");
    fieldList.Add("Address");
    fieldList.Add("City");

    ReportFilterForm report = new ReportFilterForm(fieldList);
    report.Show(this);
}
```

**ReportFilterForm.cs**

```
public ReportFilterForm(List<string> fieldListFromReport)
{
    List<string> record = new List<string>(fieldListFromReport);
    foreach(string fields in record)
    {
        listBoxFieldNames.Items.Add(fields);
    }
}
```

It throws Exception called **Null Reference Exception**

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are accessing the control before the `InitializeComponent()` method being called which is responsible for instantiating controls, so accessing controls before that ofcourse would cause **NRE (Null Reference Exception)**, make sure you call it first, there are multiple possible solutions for this. Here are those:

### Solution 1:

Call the `InitializeComponent()` before accessing the controls in your constructor:

```
public ReportFilterForm(List<string> fieldListFromReport)
{
    InitializeComponent(); // note this
    List<string> record = new List<string>(fieldListFromReport);

    foreach(string fields in record)
    {
        listBoxFieldNames.Items.Add(fields);
    }

}
```

### Solution 2:

You can call the parameter-less constructor using `this()` as normally that constructor contains call to `InitializeComponent` method:

```
public ReportFilterForm(List<string> fieldListFromReport) 
         : this() // call parameterless constructor
{

    List<string> record = new List<string>(fieldListFromReport);

    foreach(string fields in record)
    {
        listBoxFieldNames.Items.Add(fields);
    }

}
```

### Solution 3:

You can access it in `FormLoad` event as you are doing in code snippet from where it is called:

```
public class ReportFilterForm
{
    List<string> _record;
    public ReportFilterForm(List<string> fieldListFromReport)
         : this()
    {
        _record = new List<string>(fieldListFromReport);
    }

    public ReportFilterForm()
    {
         InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    public void ReportFilterForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      foreach(string fields in _record)
      {
         listBoxFieldNames.Items.Add(fields);
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: correct bro. Thanks. I will accept your answer after 10 min.

Comment: glad to help :)